# Changing the axis scale in numpy plot

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot

I am drawing a plot based on a numpy array:

```
A = np.array([[4,5,6],[2,3,6]])
```

with plt.plot(A) it works fine and draws based on 6 tuples: (0,4), (1,5), (2,6), (0,2) etc.

I want to scale the x-axis though. The units should be divided by 120. So I want to plot:

```
(0,4), (1/120,5), (2/120, 6), etc.
```

Is there any easy way to do it, without looping through the array and manually feeding the tuples to the plot?

Comment: Are you sure `plt.plot(A)` works like that?

Comment: It draws a line between those tuples in any case.

Comment: I have been reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080270/matplotlib-scale-axis-by-multiplying-with-a-constant and it seems like I need to create a new matrix with the x axis coordinates

Comment: I ran it and it gave me three plots ((0,4), (1,2)), ((0,5), (1,3)), ((0,6), (0,6))

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Yes there are three lines drawn in the plot. I want to change the x-axis of the full plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the x axis

```
scaling_factor = 120.
x = np.arange(A.shape[0])/scaling_factor
plt.plot(x, A)
```

Comment: `A.shape[1]` probably?

Comment: Well... I thought so myself, but when I did it, `plt` complained `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`. So, I'm guessing that something is off. Either the `plt.plot(A)` or the points the OP gave us.

Comment: Or with `A.shape[1]` and then `plt.plot(A, x)` maybe?

Comment: nope, that doesn't work either... You would need to transpose `A`, so

    scaling_factor = 120.
    x = np.arange(A.shape[1])/scaling_factor
    plt.plot(x, A.transpose())

Comment: The original answer with shape[0] seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Consider changing your question to be more clear and make readers understand that you have 3 plots with 2 points each

Comment: @kameranis You are modifying the data, not the scaling of the axis... What if you had 50 arrays? Scaling the data is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([4,5,6],[2,3,6])
```

This fails! What is your actual code?

Anyway have you tried providing the x values explicitely to plt.plot():

```
x = np.arange(3) / 120
plt.plot(x, whatever)
```

Comment: There are actually 2 points in each plot, so `x = np.arange(2)/120.` Also, now, your `x` is full of zeroes, because integer division. That's why you add `.` at the end, to make it a float.

Comment: Thanks. A [] was missing. My original code actually reads in the np array from a huge file.

Comment: @kameranis Python3 is out for 8 years now and does not require the . to prevent integer division.

Comment: yes, but some people still prefer to write in python2. You could be explicit about it.